# Persist a composite pattern implementation - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, composite

does anyone has a good end-to-end example of how to persist to the database a text book composite pattern from GoF such as the one below?

Component base class:

```
class Task
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def get_time_required
    0.0
  end
end
```

The composite class:

```
class CompositeTask < Task
  def initialize(name)
    super(name)
    @sub_tasks = []
  end

  def add_sub_task(task)
    @sub_tasks << task
  end

  def remove_sub_task(task)
    @sub_tasks.delete(task)
  end

  def get_time_required
    time = 0.0 
    @sub_tasks.each { |task| time += task.get_time_required }
    time
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Nearly one year late, but I feel it still be useful to extend my answer. You will need an ID for each task, let's suppose this ID is the Task's name. Then with a new parent attribute in Task you'll be able to persist the tree structure for the Composite:

```
class Task
  attr_reader :name
  attr_reader :parent

  def initialize(name, parent=nil)
    @name = name
    @parent= parent
  end

  def get_time_required
    0.0
  end
end
```

This way you will be able to navigate from parent to its children `select * from tasks where parent_id = ?` or from some child to its parent `select * from tasks where id = ?`.

Another trick is to use indexing, like in chapters, to retrieve all the hierarchy under some node. If you have a `tree_code` filed, then you can persist this way:

- root node will have 0 `tree_code`,
- root's children will have 1, 2, 3,... `tree_code` (these are first generation)
- second generation for node with `tree_code` 1 will have 1.1, 1.2,... `tree_code`. For node with `tree_code` 2 will have 2.1, 2.2,... `tree_code`
- etc.

then you will be able to retrieve all subnodes of task 1 by querying `select * from tasks where tree_code like '1.%'`.

This is always a performance trade off between insert/update vs select because you'll have to compute the `tree_code` before persisting any Component.

If you are in the context of a Rails application you can always use [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to persist the attributes to db, such as `name` and `time` (you probably want to persist it rather than assign it at runtime) and `sub_tasks`. And you only do this for the leaf tasks. You usually don't persist every single composite tasks to DB.

You can use STI(single table inheritance) to realize this pattern. You can create one base class `Task < ActiveRecord::Base` (assuming Rails4). Then you subclass a `LeafTask` and a `CompositTask` from this. Then you can persist every task you have as an instance of either one of them. If your tasks require very different interfaces, then you might want to subclass each one of them. If each of them even requires very different attributes, then you might consider multitable inheritance (i.e. they still subclass from `Task`, but they use their own tables).

Comment: Thanks. How would you persist the relationships created by the CompositeTask?